# POST'ing to a server for the contents of an <iframe>

Tags: html, iframe, xhtml

(First posting, so please be merciful if I'm off on some of the etiquette, markup, etc. :))

Server-side:

iframe-contents.php:

```
<?PHP

if($_POST['test-post-parameter'] == 'test-post-value'){
echo 'test-post-parameter successfully detected as "test-post-value".';
} else {
echo 'test-post-parameter either absent or of a different value than "test-post-value". :(';
}
?>
```

---

OK, so lets say i request iframe-contents using

`bash$ wget --post-data='test-post-parameter=test-post-value' -O - http://example.com/iframe-contents.php`

The result would be:

```
test-post-parameter successfully detected as "test-post-value".
```

---

If, however, I requested it using

```
`bash$ wget -O - http://example.com/iframe-contents.php`
```

I would end up getting:

```
test-post-parameter either absent or of a different value than "test-post-value
```

---

Now - lets say I have another file on the server, called `index.html`:

```
<html><head><title>PAGE_TITLE</title></head>
<body>
<iframe width="100%" height="100%" src="iframe-contents.php" />
</body>
```

---

If I tried typing `http://example.com/index.html` into my browser, I would get `PAGE_TITlE` in my titlebar, with `test-post-parameter either absent or of a different value than "test-post-value". :(` in the body.

My question is this: How can I modify the iframe element so that I get?

`test-post-parameter successfully detected as "test-post-value".`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot. You can do it by using GET.

With POST:
Maybe only if you make a temporary .php page, that has a form with that post value, and a javascript script that automatically post the form and redirects you to the iframe-contents.php

Something like this:

temp-iframe.php

```
<html><head>
</head>
<body onLoad="document.forms.myForm.submit()">
<form name="myForm" id="myForm" method="POST" action="iframe-contents.php">
<input type="hidden" name="test-post-parameter" value="test-post-value">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

And in the iframe src you add the: temp-ifram.php

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you can do it for post parameters, but in case you will use get method you can pass parameters explicitly:

```
<html><head><title>PAGE_TITLE</title></head>
<body>
<iframe width="100%" height="100%" src="iframe-contents.php?test-post-parameter=value" />
</body>
```